# .Yii2 creating nav menu without widget

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, yii2, navbar

Im new in yii2.  Im trying to create my own bootstrap navigation menu bar but i got this problem.

Escenario:
While using yii2 using its widget yii\bootstrap\NavBar it display the following html menu:

```
    NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => 'PLATAFORMA 3.0.0 BACKEND '. \app\models\Clientes::findOne(Yii::$app->params["id_cliente"])->nombre." (". \app\models\Proyectos::findOne(Yii::$app->params["id_proyecto"])->nombre.")",
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
    'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
],
]);
.....
echo Nav::widget([
'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();

        <nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">PLATAFORMA 3.0.0 BACKEND Axtel (axtel_experto)</a>
                </div>
                <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Configuración 
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul id="w2" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=canales%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Canales</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=productos%2Findex&amp;from_licencias=0" tabindex="-1">Productos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=atributos%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Atributos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=proyectos%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Proyecto</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=proyectos-atributos%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Proyectos-Atributos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/index.php?r=casos%2Findex&amp;from_usuarios=0">Casos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/index.php?r=usuarios%2Findex">Usuarios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Conocimiento 
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul id="w3" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=conocimiento%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Artículos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=conocimiento-categorias%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Categorías</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=subcategorias%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Subcategorias</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=secciones%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Secciones</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/index.php?r=subsecciones%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Subsecciones</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogout" data-method="post">Logout (admin)</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

It works fine. In order to create my own navbar using plain html i decided to print this html snipet, i dont know why it does not work this way. It is fine displayed but when i hover on an item that must show a submenu it does nothing.

I think that this widget triggers some js code that handles the submenu items.  Im not able to find it.

Thnx for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Renders the widget.
 */
public function run()
{
    $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($this->containerOptions, 'tag', 'div');
    echo Html::endTag($tag);
    if ($this->renderInnerContainer) {
        echo Html::endTag('div');
    }
    $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($this->options, 'tag', 'nav');
    echo Html::endTag($tag);
    BootstrapPluginAsset::register($this->getView());
}
```

This widget registers `BootstrapPluginAsset`, which contains `public $js = ['js/bootstrap.js']` ([here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-bootstrappluginasset.html#$js-detail))